# iPhone App crashes in main.m with no more information ..?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have an app and it crashes in the main.m file. The crash logs don't give much information can any one please help me debug this..

Below are the crash log...

Comment: please provide the code of main.m

Comment: Hi press command+i and select zombies run your app on simulator till the crash you will get line of code of crash

Comment: Your are making some UI changes on background thread

Comment: Looks like something is over-released. Try enabling Zombies and use the Profile tool to anlyse it. Do you ARC?

Comment: @rajneesh071 I don't see that, could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried with enabling "Zombie" in your Xcode project.

Also have a look at below tutorial, it will help you a lot:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/23704/demystifying-ios-application-crash-logs

Cheers!

Comment: Exception Break point is also a good tool to find where error occure. Have a look in this link : 1) http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions 2) http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html

Answer (score 0):

I second with Nishant,

Seeing the Crash log, I can confirm that you are releasing some object that you have marked autorelease, and when the autorelease pool drains out that object, it's reference count is already 0, now going to -1, hence crashing.

Do not release autoreleased objects.